# Ubuntu server 20.04 LTS cannot connect to internet after release upgrade

Tags: networking, dns

I did a **do-release-upgrade** on my ubuntu 20.04 LTS server, which ran successfully with some minor hiccups.
After the final reboot I could connect to the server from my local network but the internet connection fails.
It seems that the DNS does not work properly anymore, but I have no clue what makes it fail.
What is the proper way to solve the issue?

```
#host google.com
Host google.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)

# host google.com 8.8.8.8
Using domain server:
Name: 8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53
Aliases:

google.com has address 142.250.186.110
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4001:82f::200e
google.com mail is handled by 10 smtp.google.com.

# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search DOMAINS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that it is a bug with Ubuntu Server that it doesn't install netplan.io on a distro update.
To fix the problem I did set the nameserver 8.8.8.8 in /etc/resolv.conf, so that I could reach the internet.
Then I installed netplan.io and after that I still needed to create a config file for it.

```
# cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5)
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: yes
```

Then after a ***systemctl restart networking.service*** the internet connection worked.